# Remove item from state array in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

So, the user can add things through a form and they are stored in the state in an array (Acts).

The *handlePick* component is called when you click 'Start'. After that you see a 'NEXT' button which fires *handleTest*.

The idea is that when you click 'NEXT' it should remove the selectedOption from Acts and put it in playedActs, then run handlePick to get the next one.

What happenes though is that sometimes a word shows up twice (and also logs twice). So it seems like it doesn't get removed correctly.

```
state = {
    Acts: [],
    playedActs: [],
    selectedOption: undefined,
    gameOn: false
  }

}
  handleClearSelectedOption = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({ selectedOption: undefined }))
  }

handlePick = () => {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.Acts.length)
    const option = this.state.Acts[randomNum]
    this.setState(() => ({
      selectedOption: option,
      gameOn: true
    }))
  }

  handleTest = () => {
    const array = [...this.state.Acts]
    const index = array.indexOf(this.state.selectedOption)
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1)
      this.setState({ Acts: array })
    }
    this.handleClearSelectedOption()
    console.log('hello', this.state.selectedOption)
    this.handlePick()
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle producing the above issue.

Comment: @AkhilAravind I'm trying but not sure how. Maybe easier to share my the github repo?

Comment: Sure bro please do share

Comment: Here's the repo: https://github.com/jossifelefteriadis/act-it-out

Comment: Can you please remove the node_modules and commit code

Comment: Sorry forgot about it! Now they're removed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207191/discussion-between-akhil-aravind-and-jossif-elefteriadis).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have multiple `setStates` in your component its prefefred to use functional `setState`.

**Functional setState** is mainly helpful to expect correct state update when multiple `setStates` are triggered in a short interval of time where as conventional `setState` does reconciliation and could lead to unexpected state.

Here is an example code of functional setState.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   count: prevState.count + 1,
}))
```

Please check [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b/) article on Functional setState to get a clear understanding

Comment: Well, isn't that what I'm doing above? But you mean to have a functional setState within the if statement as well even though I'm only updating the Acts array? - this.setState(() => ({ Acts: array })) getting same results

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with `splice` function, it mutates the array and setState expects new state, instead you should use filter or slice functions of array.

Comment: The idea is to change the array and remove the acts already used. With filter it won't remove them